# Huge error with android opengl es 2 emulation

Tags: android, opengl-es, emulation, opengl-es-2.0

I've been at this for days, and I keep getting this...

```
`[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES 
emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-24 18:31:32 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB`
```

I already updated to all the latest tools, images, etc. I also checked the gpu emulation to yes, and I tried to see if force gpu force rendering would fix it. So far nothing. Everything else works normally. Any ideas? Oh, and I'm using windows 8. Could that be the problem?

Comment: no line triggers this. it happens whenever i start the emulator

Comment: Is there something simple to this? I need to figure this out very soon. Any suggestion would help.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Windows 8 OpenGL drivers, not emulator. Please run some simple OpenGL apps to check if everything is OK with OpenGL. BTW, what GPU do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Android emulators targeted below API level 15 [don't support graphics emulation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics), which includes OpenGL ES 2.0.

Try targeting a later API, or using something like the [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator, which supports graphics acceleration.